# Line that separates one point from $n-1$ others points.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

Given $n$ points in $\Bbb{R}^2$ noted $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

I would like to prove that exist a line that separates one point from all others.

As I am talking of points I just need to prove that there exist an affine form $l$ such that $l(x_i)<-r$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ and $l(x_n)>r$ for a number $r>0.$

So, let $m$ be a slope that differ from all line $(x_ix_j)$ and taking the linear form $l(x)=mx+b$ then I have $l(x_i)\ne l(x_j).$

Not sure how can I continue.

EDIT: **Question:** how can I continue my idea ?

Comment: Why do you believe that your idea is correct, that it can and should be continued? Maybe it's a dead end, in which case you should also be ready to accept answers that approach the problem in a completely different way.

Comment: @AlexM. Maybe it's not, is that a real question ? In any case, I was just trying to prove it with algebraic arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $n$ points be denoted $P_1,...,P_n$, and let $S = \{P_1,...,P_n\}$.

Since $S$ is finite, $S$ is bounded, so is contained in some disk, $D$ say.

Take any line which is not parallel to any of the lines through two distinct points of $S$.

Slide it in parallel until it's fully outside of $D$.

Now slide it in parallel, back towards $D$, and keep sliding it until it hits some point of $S$.

Argue that it hits exactly one point of $S$.

Now slide it in parallel a little more, but not so much as to hit another point of $S$.

Stop$\,-\,$you're done.

That was a geometric proof, and in my opinion, it's the "right" proof.

But if desired, it can easily be converted to an algebraic proof.

Here's an algebraic version of the same proof . . .

Choose a line $L$ not parallel to any of the lines between pairs of points of $S$, and suppose $L$ has the equation 
$$ax + by = c$$
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a,b$ are not both zero.

Define $c_1,...,c_n$ by

$$c_i = ax_i + by_i$$

where $P_i = (x_i,y_i)$.

Let $L_i$ be the line with equation $ax + by = c_i$.

By choice of $c_i$, the line $L_i$ hits $S$ at the point $P_i$.

But each $L_i$ is parallel to $L$.

Hence each $L_i$ hits $S$ only at the point $P_i$.

It follows that $c_1,...,c_n$ are distinct.

Relabel the points $P_1,...,P_n$ so that
$$c_1 < \cdots < c_n$$
Then the line $L'$ with equation 
$$ax + by = c'$$
$$\text{where}$$
$$c' = \frac{c_1+c_2}{2}$$

separates $P_1$ from the rest of the points of $S$.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is not really the idea but to put it in equations. Did you read my try ?

Comment: The goal was to prove there exists such a line. I gave a geometric proof.

Comment: The goal was how can I continue, but perhaps my question is not clear.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to insist on continuing _your_ proof. But if you compare my proof to your attempt, you should be able to adapt my strategy so as to complete the proof in your preferred style.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for you algebraic proof!

Comment: (I was not really insisting to continuing my proof but just the algebraic version it's perfect)